# Lock windows phone emulator

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, screen, windows-phone-7-emulator

I am making a app for windows phone. I use visual studio 2010 and the windows phone sdk which includes the windows phone emulator. My program crashes when i lock the phone's screen (actual device). So i decided to fix this issue. but now i found out that there is no way to debug this because the emulators screen can't be locked.

Is there any way to lock (screen of) the window phone emulator?

Comment: Have you tested your app by pressing home button and then resuming the app? If that reproduces your problem, then you can use the same in emulator as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are replacement emulator ROMS that some clever developers have created/hacked, like http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13488/test-all-features-of-windows-phone-7-on-your-pc/

They enable additional features, including screen lock/unlock, that MS chose to turn off in the basic emulator.

Best try find the latest, and best-rated, version of these replacement ROMS before attempting them.

### Also please note as they repeat in that article:

*This modified emulator image is not official, and isn’t sanctioned by Microsoft. Use your own judgment when choosing to download and use the emulator*

Answer (score 2):

**Press F12**

This is what msdn says about it

> To lock the screen in the emulator by using the keyboard
>   With the emulator open, press F12 on your computer keyboard twice.
>   The F12 key emulates the power button on the phone. The first key press turns off the display. The second key press turns the display on again with the lock screen engaged.
>   You can unlock the screen by using the mouse to slide the lock screen upward.

I hope it would work for Windows Phone 7 as well. but not sure

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Phone 8, you can simulate lock screen through Visual Studio's Simulation Dashboard under Tools menu.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206951(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_lockoptions

Comment: the question was about the windowsphone 7 emulator, not about the windowsphone 8 version :)

Answer (score 0):

For windows 8 emulators you can also press the power button with your mouse:

[image]